# UIImageView Border Color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cgcolor

I have the following code:

```
UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:182 green:10 blue:96 alpha:1.0];
[viewImage.layer setBorderColor:borderColor.CGColor];
[viewImage.layer setBorderWidth:3.0];
[productView addSubview:viewImage];
```

where `viewImage` is my `UIImageView` and `productView` is my `UIView`.

I want to get this color [image], but all I am getting is this color [image]. I tried different values, and all the colors that I am getting is either white, red, black, yellow, or blue. I can't get any other colors, doesn't matter what values I enter. I tried colorWithHue:Saturation:Brightness and I have the same issue.

I am using this on iOS 6 SDK.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The values for red green and blue should be beween 0.0 and 1.0. 
From UIColor doc:

Values below 0.0 are interpreted as 0.0, and values above 1.0 are interpreted as 1.0.

Comment: Damn. Stupid mistake. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: for sure. if you wanna use rgb values though, I think you can just divide the values you have by 255

Answer (score 16):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift version 2.11 (Xcode 7.2.1):

```
let borderColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:1.0)
viewImage.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
viewImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Comment: CGColor should be changed to cgColor in swift 3